# Plotting the DC component of a Fourier Series in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot the DC component of the Fourier Series together with the harmonics in the first panel. But the first panel only outputs the harmonics. Please help me in solving this one. Below is my code and output plot.

```
n = 30;
x = (0:300)/100;
xx = 2*x;
ao = 1/2;           %DC component
f = ones(1,301)*ao;
for i = 1:2:n
    bn = 2/pi/i;
    bnx = bn*sin(2*pi*i*x);
    f = f + bnx;
    subplot(1,2,1)
    plot(xx,ao)     %Plotting of DC component
    hold on
    plot(xx,bnx)
    hold on
    subplot(1,2,2)
    plot(xx,f)
    hold off
end
```

[image: Output Plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line

> `plot(xx,ao)     %Plotting of DC component`

Here `xx` is a vector and `ao` is a number. From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#description), in this case the `plot` function plots discrete points; and these are not even visible because no marker has been specified.

To obtain a horizontal line of height `ao`, you need to replace the above by the following, so that both inputs to `plot` are vectors:

```
plot(xx,repmat(ao,size(xx)))
```

In addition, it would be better to move this line of code, together with `subplot(1,2,1)` and `hold on`, before the loop, to plot the DC component only once:

```
n = 30;
x = (0:300)/100;
xx = 2*x;
ao = 1/2;                      %DC component
f = ones(1,301)*ao;
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(xx,repmat(ao,size(xx)))   %Plotting of DC component
hold on
for i = 1:2:n
    bn = 2/pi/i;
    bnx = bn*sin(2*pi*i*x);
    f = f + bnx;
    subplot(1,2,1)
    plot(xx,bnx)
    subplot(1,2,2)
    plot(xx,f)
    hold off
end
```

[image]